# Boost don't generate CSS

Tags: theming, caching

I have a major problem: the boost module is great but SOMETIMES i find some pagers without any CSS or JS like the image below:
[image]

Comment: What's the HTTP status of the CSS (and probably JS) files that seems missing?

Comment: try to change from %{HTTP_HOST} to any other two options. ie (Servers URL or Name) or %{SERVER_NAME} . Under your boost setting

Comment: Do you have both Boost and Drupal cache running? Make sure you have set it so when CRON runs "Purge expired cache files" as CSS will regenerate when CRON runs and if you don't purge it will look for old css.

Comment: @Mołot : how to get the HTTP status info of the CSS?

Comment: In Firefox use Firebug extension. In Chrome console is built in. Hit F12, go to network tab, refresh page.

Comment: @Bala:it happens not all the times, just sometimes, and i don't know why?

Comment: @pgrujic: Drupal cache is disabled, Remove old cache files on cron is enabled, Ignore a cache flush command if cron issued the request is enabled too

Comment: @Mołot:for now i can't find any wrong page, if i'll find it i'll tell you

Comment: @Mołot: here is a life exemple of this issue: http://sahara-question.com/fr/content/rappel-historique

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not here 24/7 and your example is no longer valid. Please post the HTTP responses themselves in your question, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

https://drupal.org/project/advagg/ should solve this issue. Odds are the cached page is older than 30 days (limit of CSS/JS aggregates in D7 Core).

Comment: ok i will test it and tell you the result

Comment: i test it, and the problem still persist unfortunately, is there any special configuration for the advagg

Comment: Couple of quick points. This will not fix already missing CSS files; it will only prevent them from happening in the future. What's an example filename of the missing CSS file? If it doesn't reference the advagg_css dir then AdvAgg can't help. After advagg is working, recommend clearing the boost cache so the cached html will point to AdvAgg CSS.

Comment: after installing the AdvAgg module i run the cron, and i after i enabled the core JSS and CSS compresssion,here is an exemple of a url with this issue, and as u can see it happend at 21h26min http://sahara-question.com/fr/actualites/alg%C3%A9rie-rapport-accablant-cfda

Comment: Could you reply in here https://drupal.org/node/2082333 ? I don't currently see the issue.

Comment: Ok i will.. the issue happens randomly. . For now take http://sahara-question.com/fr